# Is there a way to make the broccoli less compiler respect the multiple outputPaths config for CSS files?

Tags: ember.js, less, ember-cli, broccolijs

i'm using ember-cli 0.1.5,

I'd like to build a css file for each 'skin-*.less' file in the app/styles folder. This works with plain CSS using the following config in my Brocfile.js:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    outputPaths: {
        app: {
            css: {
                'skin-light': '/assets/skin-light.css',
                'skin-dark': '/assets/skin-dark.css'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

After installing a LESS precompiler with 'ember install:addon ember-cli-less' this config is not respected and instead 'ember build' looks for app/styles/app.less.

Is there a way to make the broccoli less compiler respect the multiple outputPaths config for CSS files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is now available in ember-cli-less v1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

It would [appear not](https://github.com/gdub22/ember-cli-less/pull/3); that’s a pull request for that very functionality, but it’s reportedly buggy.